# Get max value sql in Java

Tags: java, sql, max

*I don't get value of max in function other. Value return is "0". I trying but not success :(
 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhgNI.png)

```
public int PriceMax(int manhom){
        Connection conn = this.connect();
        int max = 0;
        if(conn != null){
            try {
                java.sql.Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT AVG(GiaSP) from tbsanpham where manhom = '"+manhom+"'";
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                max = rs.getInt(sql);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CSDL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

**Help!!!**

```
int manhom = cbbNhomSanPham.getSelectedIndex();
        CSDL csdl = new CSDL();
        int max = csdl.PriceMax(manhom);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nhóm sản phẩm: '"+cbbNhomSanPham.getName()+"' \nPrice max: '"+max+"' ");
```

Comment: `max = rs.getInt(sql);`? Does this code even compile?

Comment: Ok, I try change object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using it as it should be.

First of all, you use `AVG` but want `MAX` so change it to `MAX(GiaSP)`. Second, you must use `rs.next()` to have your cursor go to the first row and then get information from it.

```
java.sql.Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT MAX(GiaSP) from tbsanpham where manhom = '"+manhom+"'";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
if (rs.next()) {
    max = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: I have a mistake "avg" with "max" @@

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select MAX(GiaSP) as maxGiaSP from tbsanpham where manhom = '"+manhom+"'");
if (rs.next())
{
    int w = rs.getInt("maxGiaSP ");

    // just return this int
}
```